# How to change the User Portal language in Bonitasoft 7x?

Tags: bonita

I need to change the language of my Portal in **Bonitasoft 7.x**, I obtained through the documentation found [here](http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/?page=languages), to make available the option **(Portuguese - BR)** in the language settings of my portal:

[image]

But selecting this option ends up being unconfigured the portal page and does not change anything, so the page stays like this:

[image]

Comment: We are currently expecting some issue with the collaborative translation platform we use. Once that is fixed I'll do a test to install Portuguese translation and get back to you with the result.

Comment: @AntoineMottier Thanks your answer, i await your return

Comment: I identified the root cause of the issue. On our translation platform (Crowdin), we have 3 branches: 7.3.x, 7.4.x and dev. If a string is translated in one of this branch it is automatically replicated to all other branches. Issue is that the Portuguese translation of the main branch (7.4.x) is currently empty. 7.3.x translation is reported as 100% complete because all strings that are specific to 7.3.x (i.e. not listed in 7.4.x) are translated. Additionally 7.0.x translation is not configured as a branch but instead as a "folder". So 7.0.x translated string are not shared with other branches.

Comment: I'll try to convert 7.0.x "folder" to a "branch" or at least merge the 7.0.x translated strings with 7.4.x branch.

Comment: @AntoineMottier I was able to translate the portaql in this way. I downloaded the * .po translation file for Bonita version 7.3.x, then opened the file and transferred its translation to the Bonita version 7.4.x file, so by placing it in the i18n folder the portal had been translated correctly

Comment: Can you confirm that you managed to get translation for example for the "Settings" link on top right corner of the Portal page? Right now I don't understand how this can work because none of the various versions include a translation for this string. If you have a file with more translation that was is currently available on Crowdin can you try to upload it?

Comment: @AntoineMottier Just to understand, you want in case I make my translation file available on Crowdin?

Comment: First I want to clarify if you get the translation for string such as "Settings" from what we provide on Crowdin? If you actually didn't get it from Crowdin but instead added yourself to the file you download from Crowdin it would be nice if you can actually make your translation available on Crowdin on bonita-bpm project. Thanks.

Comment: @AntoineMottier I took the translation file made available in Crowdin but the file was blank in the translations part, so I translated the lines myself and it worked out after that, but I do not know how to put my file in the crowdin to help those who need it

Comment: @AntoineMottier You would have an email that could send you a question I'm having about BonitaSoft's UI Designer 7.3x?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was caused by a temporary inconsistency in the translation. For now on the [instructions](https://documentation.bonitasoft.com/bonita/7.8/languages) available in documentation should provide the needed guidance to install any translation as long as the translation covered all the strings used in Bonita Portal.